Can I simplify deconstructing object type to array of objects type with Type Mapping?
I have something like:
interface Foo {
  SubAccount: boolean; 
  Classification: "Asset" | "Liability"; 
  AccountSubType: string
}

A relevant function can accept either an object (Foo) or (|) array (FooOptions[]) as a parameter;
FooOptions is derived from Foo but just in a different format:
type FooOptions = {field: string; value: unknown}.

I'd like to create FooOptions from the Foo type.
I would like to use something like this:
type FooOptions= {field: keyof Foo; value: Foo[keyof Foo]}

But instead have to use:
type FooOptions=   
  {field: "SubAccount"; value: Foo["SubAccount"]} 
| {field: "Classification"; value: Foo["Classification"]} 
| {field: "AccountSubType", value: Foo["AccountSubType"]}

The field property populates but not the value.
Is there any way this will work?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! • What does "AofO" mean? Is that an acronym? I did a web search for it but I can't find anything obviously relevant. Could you [edit] the title to either expand what it stands for or replace it with a more conventional term? • Please [edit] the code to be a [mre]; you should define AccountQuery for is as code instead of or in addition to the verbal description of it. Something easy for us to copy and paste into an IDE, so we can get started on it. And is ...Possibility something different or just another name for the same thing as ...Options?

• Please see previous comment and make recommended edits. Once you do that, does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Sorry, it was array of objects. No sure why I thought that was a known acronym, maybe should be lol . Either way, describing the ask was a challenge.
I think I fixed the post? Thank you for the guidance.
You're snippet seems to do what I was looking for! I was generally curious about this kind of "reshaping" capabilities in typescript.

Also looks like a repeat question.
Would it be impossible to use other array values to check types? For instance, I'm using Discriminated Unions for the object, but what about this array?
If I add {field: "Classification", value: "Asset"} then {field: "SubAccount", value: true} throws an error.
